# Plotting values from an NSArray in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

**Edit: added Dump(lat)**
**Edit2: tried compactMap**

I am having trouble retrieving values from an SQL database and plotting longitude and latitude from each row in the database as a new pin on the Map. The problem arises from when I try to retrieve the values from the array

```
var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()

func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    
    feedItems = items
    var i = 0
    for selectedLoc in feedItems {
        i+=1
        let lat = selectedLoc
        let lati = 55.74  /// should be gathered from the json extracted from the sql
        let longi = 10.88 /// should be gathered from the json
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    }
```

dump(lat) looks like this:

```
▿ Name: Optional("1"), Time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00"), Latitude: Optional("55.73390° N"), Longitude: Optional(" 12.57243° E") #0
  - super: NSObject
  ▿ name: Optional("1")
    - some: "1"
  ▿ time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00")
    - some: "2021-11-13 00:00:00"
  ▿ latitude: Optional("55.73390° N")
    - some: "55.73390° N"
  ▿ longitude: Optional(" 12.57243° E")
    - some: " 12.57243° E"
▿ Name: Optional("2"), Time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00"), Latitude: Optional("54.73390° N"), Longitude: Optional(" 11.57243° E") #0
  - super: NSObject
  ▿ name: Optional("2")
    - some: "2"
  ▿ time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00")
    - some: "2021-11-13 00:00:00"
  ▿ latitude: Optional("54.73390° N")
    - some: "54.73390° N"
  ▿ longitude: Optional(" 11.57243° E")
    - some: " 11.57243° E"
▿ Name: Optional("3"), Time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00"), Latitude: Optional("56.73390° N"), Longitude: Optional(" 13.57243° E") #0
  - super: NSObject
  ▿ name: Optional("3")
    - some: "3"
  ▿ time_in: Optional("2021-11-13 00:00:00")
    - some: "2021-11-13 00:00:00"
  ▿ latitude: Optional("56.73390° N")
    - some: "56.73390° N"
  ▿ longitude: Optional(" 13.57243° E")
    - some: " 13.57243° E"
```

I just need to retrieve the latitude from this and insert it into the "lati" and "
longi" variables. I have tried many many things such as

```
    let lati = lat[latitude]
    let lati = lat.latitude
```

These give the error: "Value of type 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'latitude'".
I am sure it is just very simple but I am stuck. Can anyone help out a stupid newbie?

```
    let locs = feedItems.compactMap{ Int($0 as! String)}
```

Resulted in Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

Comment: `if let lat as? YourObject { let lati = lat.latitude }`. BUT, since you are using Swift, in Swift+3, prefers to avoid `NSStuff` when there is a Swift equivalent: NSArray => Array. So: `var feedItems: [YourObject] = [YourObject]()` you'll avoid the cast then?.

Comment: `NSArray` is a type from Objective-C. It is an untyped array, so we can't tell what's in it. (And neither can the compiler.)

It looks like the records in your array are dictionaries of type `[String:String?]`? (String key and Optional string value).

Can you give more information about the structure of your array of lats/longitudes?

What does your dump function look like, for example?

Comment: You also may find that instead of iterating through each of the `feedItems`, that you use `compactMap` to return an array of annotations, and then add them all at once to the map.